# How to pull specific cells from numerous excel sheets into a data frame in R

Tags: r, excel

I have some data from genetics researchers that needs to be analyzed.  The issue is they gave me the data in an excel sheet that looks like a scientific journal.  I need to pull certain cells (not a range of cells, but individual cells) from 89 different sheets within an excel file into a data frame in R.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

save your file as `.csv` from excel

use `read.csv2()` using the parameters

```
row.names = c("M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"), 
col.names= c("X", "Y", "Z", "A","B"),
```

Comment: The OP said they need to pull cells from 89 different sheets. Saving as a CSV file would only include 1 sheet. This doesn't seem to answer the question (which is currently too broad to answer well anyway)